# How to scroll until a specific element in a flex-box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am buliding a react app. I have a flex-box which contains buttons with patients' names from right to left, and it is inside of a container that allows scrolling if the flex-box is overflowing. Whenever a name is clicked, i want it to scroll left so the name that was clicked will appear in the most right of the container (in a way that if you will scroll to the right, you will see the other names that are to the right of the selected name).

this is the container:

```
<div className="flex-box-container" ref={outerDivRef}>
    <FlexBox onBoxClick={scrollToSection} />
</div>
```

that passes this function to the flex-box:

```
const scrollToSection = (id: number) => {
        const section = outerDivRef.current.children[0].querySelector(
            `[id='${id}']`, 
        ); 

        if (section) {
            section.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth",
                block: "nearest",
                inline: "start",
            });
        }
    };
```

this is FlexBox:

```
<div className="flex-box" ref={containerRef}>
            {PEOPLE.map((person) => (
                 <button
                    key={person.name+person.id}
                    id={person.id}
                    onClick={() => onBoxClick(person.id)}
        >
            {name}
        </button>
            ))}
</div>
```